# upcoming date of birth issue in query before 1970 with unix time stamp with mysql

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I need help for this query

Now I am using unix time stamp for saving date of birth of user

I have this query for getting upcoming date of birth for users. 
Its working only for after 1970 dob like  1986-09-18 (Y-m-d)
But Its not working before 1970 dob like 1969-09-18 (Y-m-d)

```
SELECT u.id, u.dob
FROM hrs_employee_details u 
WHERE CONCAT( IF( MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( u.dob ) ) =1 AND MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) = 12, YEAR( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) +1, YEAR( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) ) , DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( u.dob ) , '-%m-%d' ) ) 
BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE() , INTERVAL 14 DAY ) AND u.dob <> '' ;
```

Please help me ASAP
thanks in advance...

Comment: Let's see.. use `DATETIME`, the type that was specifically made for such purposes?

Comment: Or even better - use the DATE type (unless you know the actual time of birth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before, use DATE(TIME) fields for this, it's much easier to work with.

But to get the age of negative timestamps as well:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL dob second))), '%Y')+0 AS age FROM hrs_employee_details
```

Comment: could we use between query instead of above query? Because its giving all records form table.

Comment: Sure, it was just an example:

SELECT u.id, u.dob FROM hrs_employee_details u WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL dob second))), '%Y')+0 BETWEEN 20 AND 30

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support UNIX timestamps for dates prior to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (i.e. negative timestamps). Function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` returns [unsigned integer values only](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and it is [unlikely to change](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8212). Function `FROM_UNIXTIME` returns `NULL` for any negative argument.